# cant reaolve following error android one intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When i run the project or start the new project i am getting the following error

AAPT err (10539517):I:\AndroidProject\RxPlayer\app\build\intermediates\exploded-arr\com.android.support\appcompt-v7\22.0.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png:libpng warning: iccp : Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

can this happen if i disable windows services as i had disable some of it to boost system speed when i had installed android one no error .but from past 2-3 days i am receiving errors while debuging current project and also when i start new project i also receive the error and its frustrating and getting no solution if some one knows how to solve plese send the solution on mail id :- renku9999@yahoo.ca

Answer (score 0):

Should have been fixed by now...update Android Studio and your build sdk tools via sdk manager.

If that doesnt work, reinstall.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629